# What does this bit of code mean? (Pug template engine)

Tags: node.js, pug, templating

The code in question is part of a layout [here](https://github.com/bradtraversy/nodekb/blob/master/views/layout.pug). This code displays errors if there are any. I don't understand what `!= messages('message', locals)` does in this context:

```
.container
  != messages('message', locals)
  if errors
    each error, i in errors
      div #{error.msg}
```

1. What does `!=` here do? (In [documentation](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html) it says it prefaces unescaped buffered code - how does that apply here?
2. What does `messages('message', locals)` do, and where does `locals` come from?

Comment: Is there a `messages` javascript function defined somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `!=` implies that a string passed will be unescaped. If the string has html tags they will be interpreted as html tags. So the statement blow

```
p != 'This is a <b>bold<b> statement!'
```

will be  rendered as

> This is a **bold** statement

---

The `=` argument will escape the text. The `<` sign among other things will be changeg to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;`

```
p = 'This is a <b>bold<b> statement!'
```

will be rendered as

> This is a <b>bold<b> statement

---

Express allows you to store values which can be passed between middlewares. These can be stored in the `res.locals` object. This object is available to pug as a variable `locals`.

The statement `messages('message', locals)` here seems to be using the `express-messages` module available [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-messages)

In the app.js file, a express middleware sets the `locals` variable so it's available to all routes.

```
res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
```